# Why is my data being interpreted as a readable stream instead of a json object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm building a simple REST API in Kotlin and front-end with React. I'm pretty new to Kotlin and Spring, but I've managed to get a simple service working with Postman. I'm able to return all objects in an SQL table using JpaRepository interface. When I make the call through Postman, my output is as expected (looks like a normal Json object).

However, when I make the call through a standard react fetch the body is produced as a ReadableStream {locked: false}. I did some research on readable streams and they appear to mostly be for images. I tried body.getReader() from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams, but that did not work either.

Here is my Kotlin code:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/catalog")
class ArtworkController (
    private val artworkService: ArtworkService
        ) {


    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("")
    @ResponseBody
    fun getData(): MutableList<Artwork> {
//        println(artworkService.getArt().javaClass.kotlin)
        return artworkService.getArt()
    }


}

@Service
class ArtworkService(
    private val artworkRepository: ArtworkRepository
){

    fun getArt(): MutableList<Artwork> {
        return artworkRepository.findAll()
    }
}
```

These are in separate files - just joined them here for brevity.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can remove ResponseBody annotation because RestController is containing: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html

Comment: Your react what media type is waiting for? This will send "application/json" not any stream.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was immediately returning a promise and had to set up an async function to handle the request.

```
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery("repoData", 
  async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://url_here")
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json()
    }
  
  )  
  setData(data)
  }
```

For context, this request is wrapped in react-query but works without it as well.